# Python - Printing a ctype string buffer in my Read/WriteProcessMemory application

Tags: python, memory, buffer, ctypes, readprocessmemory

Let me say that this was my first attempt at a proper memory reading and writing application. The writing function isn't even implemented yet but it will come in time. Just don't flame me for the code.

First thing is the complete program for so everyone can see (don't comment on my "bad coding choices", the thing works and I get the process handle and ID just fine)

```css
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes
from time import *
import win32ui, win32process ,win32api

PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = 0x1F0FFF

ReadProcessMemory = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32',use_last_error=True).ReadProcessMemory
ReadProcessMemory.argtypes = [wintypes.HANDLE,wintypes.LPCVOID,wintypes.LPVOID,ctypes.c_size_t,ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_size_t)]
ReadProcessMemory.restype = wintypes.BOOL

WriteProcessMemory = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32',use_last_error=True).WriteProcessMemory
WriteProcessMemory.argtypes = [wintypes.HANDLE,wintypes.LPVOID,wintypes.LPCVOID,ctypes.c_size_t,ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_size_t)]
WriteProcessMemory.restype = wintypes.BOOL

def main():
    WindowName = input("Enter the window name: ")
    if (len(WindowName) > 0):
        Process, pID = attach(WindowName)
        Choice = input("Read or Write?").lower()
        if (Choice == "write"):
            #DoWriteMethod
            pass
        if (Choice == "read"):
            Read(Process)

    else:
        print("Invalid Window Name!\n\n")
        sleep(2)
        return 0

def attach(WindowName):
    try: 
        hWnd = win32ui.FindWindow(None,WindowName).GetSafeHwnd()
    except:
        print("Window not found!\n\n")
        sleep(2)
        return 0,0

    pID = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd)[1]
    Process = win32api.OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,0,pID).handle

    print("\nProcess = ", Process)
    print("ProcessID = ", pID)

    return Process,pID

def Write():
    return 0

def Read(Process):
    Address = input("Enter the address in hexadecial (0x form) \n")
    if (Address[0] == "0" and Address[1] == "x"):
        BufferAddress = ctypes.create_string_buffer(64)
        ptr = ctypes.pointer(BufferAddress)
        ReadProcessMemory(Process,Address,BufferAddress,64,None)
        print("Pointer contains: ", BufferAddress, "\n\n")
        main()
    else:
        print("Invalid address!\n\n")
        sleep(2)
        Read(Process)
    return 0

if (main() == 0):
    main()
if (main() == 1):
    exit(0)
```

On line 54 I create a 'ctype.create_string_buffer(64)'

I then use this in ReadProcessMemory where the value should be stored but whenever I print it on line 57 it just returns the following:

```
Enter the window name: New Tab - Google Chrome

Process =  608
ProcessID =  2844

Read or Write?Read

Enter the address in hexadecial (0x form) 
0x1A6606BE380

Pointer contains:  <ctypes.c_char_Array_64 object at 0x000001A0101D78C8>
```

I know this value should be 90 (found a random address in cheat engine) so it must contain the value 90? How could I find this value.

I am using Python 3.5.0 and the corresponding win32 modules package from

'pip install pypiwin32'

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the object.  Print the contents:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> BufferAddress = ctypes.create_string_buffer(64)
>>> print(BufferAddress)
<ctypes.c_char_Array_64 object at 0x0000000003124248>
>>> dir(BufferAddress)
['__class__', '__ctypes_from_outparam__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__f
ormat__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__',
'__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__setstate_
_', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_b_base_', '_b_needsfree_', '_length_', '_objects', '_t
ype_', 'raw', 'value']
>>> BufferAddress.raw
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x
00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x
00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>> BufferAddress.raw[0]
0
```